# Read a text in JSON format and extract value

Tags: json

I have JSON file that I must read it and extract the id from it. I made class by "http://json2csharp.com/" and also wrote an script. because of complexity of the JSON format my class is a bit strange (at least it is strange for me) and that's why I am totally confused. May check the script and tell me how I have to extract the id.
BTW= I found some codes through "stackoverflow" and used them before.

the total procedure of script:
1-read an access dataset which has two fields(uid,tid)-3000 records
2-read every uid from dataset and replace  (the tag which is in url) with uid(which is in table) in url
3-run url and read json file and if (id==tid)  -> counter++.

json format:

```
    {
      "context": "65071",
      "names": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "hash",
        "score",
        "rank"
      ],
      "values": [
        [
          "187126",
          "187126",
          "187126",
          "0.1",
          "92.7157"
        ],
        [
          "494579",
          "494579",
          "494579",
          "0.05",
          "77.6358"
        ],
        [
          "455577",
          "455577",
          "455577",
          "0.0488174",
          "76.4856"
        ].....

 ,
  "kola": 6,
  "swer": "v3-beta"
}
```

the json class

```
public class Class1
    {
        public string context{ get; set; }
        public List<string> names { get; set; }
        public List<List<string>> values { get; set; }
        public int kloa { get; set; }
        public string swer { get; set; }
    }
```

script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace test6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\xa.accdb";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from xa";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //To read data from dataset
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            int uid = 0;
            int tid = 0;
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string url = "http://opkug/<uid>?groups=<uid>";
                var test = url.Replace("<uid>", Convert.ToString(row[uid]));
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test);
                string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(test);
                var pi = JObject.Parse(client);
                List<List<string>> ids = values.Select(v => v[field_names.IndexOf("idz")]).ToList();
                if(ids == Convert.ToString(row[tid]))
                   {
                    counter++;
                   }
            }

            Console.ReadLine(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you are actually asking

Comment: I am not sure about these three lines at all....................var pi = JObject.Parse(client);
                List<List<string>> ids = values.Select(v => v[field_names.IndexOf("idz")]).ToList();
                if(ids == Convert.ToString(row[tid]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably make use of *Newton Soft’s JSON .NET* which is an open source utility available at http://json.codeplex.com/

You can also [see this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/23/10425845.aspx) which is for Windows phone but since it is C# it should work for you also.

Comment: what is the exact problem you are having? your question is a bit vague. I have used this library personally and found it quite powerful.

Comment: I am not sure about these three lines in my code at all.because I just found it throug the internet and tried to use it...................var pi = JObject.Parse(client); List<List<string>> ids = values.Select(v => v[field_names.IndexOf("idz")]).ToList(); if(ids == Convert.ToString(row[tid]))

Comment: It seems to me you are not really using newtonsoft... call : var pi=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<#classname#>(client); 
where classname is the class you got from Json2Csharp

Comment: thank you @Wajahat. and now how can I read only id from this class?

Comment: As you can see, id is the first element of names array. So, pi.names[0] will give you id.